# How to restrict generic function to accept only some type of classes

Tags: c#, generics

I'm trying to do the following:

```
public class A
{
}

public class B
{
}
```

Somewhere along the project I want to have this:

```
public class C
{
    public T func<T>(T obj) [where T can be either of class A or class B]
    {
        obj.x = 100;

        return obj;
    }
}
```

I've been trying:

```
public T func<T>(T obj) where T: A, B
```

but this gives me:

> The type class constraint 'B' must come before any other constraint.

Can someone explain me how to make `func` accept only class A or class B?

Comment: If you can do a base class or an interface `BaseForAandB`, then you'll be able to set a constraint like `where T: BaseForAandB`

Comment: You can use interfaces for this purpose but you cant do this if you cant change the classes.

Comment: What is the practical problem are you trying to solve by accepting either `A` or `B`? Are you exploiting some commonality between the two classes? Do you not want other classes to get the functionality associated with your generic class, even if they could fit the requirements of the generic?

Comment: If you only want some types of classes, you probably should NOT use a generic. Create a common base class for your classes and have a method that uses that, or if you can't get it down to one common class create a few of them and use overload resolution.

Comment: I totally agree with Joel Coehoorn. You can create 3 overloads. 1 method is base method and its private. 2 other overloads are public that you can call them with `A` or `B`. do the separated job inside 2 public methods and do the shared job inside private method. or you can create only 2 overloads if number of lines are not much. also this is how .Net libraries implemented ;)

Comment: Remember, if your code only works with two types then it is not *generic*. Generic code should ideally work with any type; that's what makes it *generic*.

Comment: Guys, you've all been an enormous help. The real problem is that I don't fully understand generics. I should look to it some time. For now I understood why things doesn't work the way I expect. So I'll just turn to the overload solution. It is less pretty in my opinion, but I have to go on quickly on this matter. Thank you very much for your time and efforts, you are very kind and helpful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Exactly as it's described in the question, this job is better handled by **overload resolution**:

```
public class C
{
    public A func(A obj)
    {
        obj.x = 100;   
        return obj;
    }

    public B func(B obj)
    {
        obj.x = 100;   
        return obj;
    }

}
```

But I understand that A and B may be placeholders for any number of types, and it could get tedious to account for them all. In that case, you'll need a common interface that's supported by each of your classes:

```
interface IBase
{
    int x;
}

public class C
{
    public IBase func(IBase obj)
    {
        obj.x = 100;   
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Note that at this point we still have no need of generics. Additionally, you may need to support a number of types that won't all fit together under a common interface. In this case, *still build the interface* and put as many types with that interface as possible. If needed, build another interface for a few more types ... and so on... and then between interfaces and specific types you can handle things with overload resolution.

Answer (score 2):

You need some kind of common base for both the classes, either have them implement the same interface as the below code or have them inherit from same class. You can not have a generic constrained to 2 types.

```
public interface IFooBar
{
    void DoThis();
}

public class Foo : IFooBar
{
    public void DoThis()
    {
        //Do something
    }
}

public class Bar : IFooBar
{
    public void DoThis()
    {
        //Do something
    }
}

public class C
{
    public T func<T>(T obj) where T : IFooBar
    {
        obj.DoThis();
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Comment: Good job suggesting use of common interface instead of a base class

Comment: Why not just `public IFooBar func(IFooBar obj) {obj.DoThis();return obj;}`?

Comment: OP says, the user is not familiar with generics and want to use generics for some reason. This answer explains *how* to do that.

Answer (score 0):

The generics classes are just like any other class, you can't (and shouldn't) have multiple inheritance of classes, you can inherit one class and multiple interfaces.

in your case you should apply an interface on both classes and restrict the generics on that interface.

you can see some documentation in:
[Constraints on Type Parameters (C# Programming Guide)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
interface IMarkerInterface{} // there is a such pattern called marker  
                             // interface . No need to have methods if there 
                            // is no need for, A and B can just implement it 

public class A: IMarkerInterface
{
}

public class B: IMarkerInterface
{
}

public class C
{
    public T func<T>(T obj).Where T:IMarkerInterface
    {
        obj.x = 100;
        return obj;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`public T func<T>(T obj) where T: A, B` this means `T` should extend both `A` and `B` , but multiple inheritance is not valid in `C#` ,so it won't work.

You could do one of  the following though :

1. you could make `A` and `B` have a common parent via an `interface` or an `abstract` class , but that would be code modification.
2. since both `A` and `B` have a default no-arg constructor you could use `where T: new()`.

Also, you can not do `obj.x = 100;` as there is no way to guarantee that`T` will have a instance variable `x`.