# Is there a way to pass a generic form type and use it to show the form?

Tags: c#

My question is can i pass a generic type of form and use it to show the form?

```
public void ucitajFormu<T>()
{
     T forma = new T();
     forma.Show();
}
```

Comment: Related : [How to restrict generic function to accept only some type of classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33590867/how-to-restrict-generic-function-to-accept-only-some-type-of-classes)

Answer (score 1):

you probably need a generic constraint:

```
public void ucitajFormu<T>() where T: Form, new()
{
     T forma = new T();
     forma.Show();
}
```

the `T: Form` means that every type must inherit from `Form`, and the `new()`-constraint means, that the type needs to be instantiable (thus no abstract types) using a parameterless constructor.